# Specified cast is not valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table created in ASP.net and I want to populate the table with information from the database once the page has been loaded. I'm getting an error that the specified cast is not valid. What am I doing wrong?  Heres my code

```
public string getData()
{
        string htmlStr = "";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * from INFO";
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DateTime Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
            DateTime Time = reader.GetDateTime(1);
            htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + Date + "</td><td>"  + Time + "</td></tr>";                  
        }

        conn.Close();

        return htmlStr;
}
```

---

```
<table style="width:100%">
                <caption>INFO</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td> Date </td>
                    <td> Time </td>
                </tr>
                    <%=getData()%>
                </table>
```

This is my error:

[image: This is my error]

It is throwing the exception on this line from the above code:

```
DateTime Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
```

Comment: @Grant this line `DateTime Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);` was throwing the exception

Comment: Ok, I'm able to get past the Date now, but it's throwing the time exception now?

Comment: time(7) is the datatype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your comment:

> this line `DateTime Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);` was throwing the exception

The first column is not a valid DateTime. Most likely, you have multiple columns in your table, and you're retrieving them *all* by running this query:

```
SELECT * from INFO
```

Replace it with a query that retrieves *only* the two columns you're interested in:

```
SELECT YOUR_DATE_COLUMN, YOUR_TIME_COLUMN from INFO
```

Then try reading the values again:

```
var Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
var Time = reader.GetTimeSpan(1);  // equivalent to time(7) from your database
```

Or:

```
var Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["YOUR_DATE_COLUMN"]);
var Time = (TimeSpan)reader["YOUR_TIME_COLUMN"];
```

Comment: I'm going to try this again, but it's not throwing the date exception anymore

Comment: This worked once I change Time from DateTime to TimeSpan. Thanks very much. The only problem I have now, and its not that big of a one. But, for the Date, it displays the date and then 00:00:00 after it

Comment: this is the answer, you're selecting the wrong columns, if your table has an identity table then you're selecting the id with 0 most likely. Always specify the column names using `reader["columnname"]` instead of the number because table structure is  always subject to change.

Comment: @notc1 to get rid of the 00:00:00 use `Date.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: @GrantWinney thats was usful buy anyway to format date as follow dd/mm/yyyy ??

Answer (score 0):

`htmlStr` is string then You need to `Date` and `Time` variables to `string`

```
while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DateTime Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    DateTime Time = reader.GetDateTime(1);
                    htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + Date.ToString() + "</td><td>"  + 
                    Time.ToString() + "</td></tr>";                  
                }
```

Comment: @notc1 mention what is `getData()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void LoadData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Stocks;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From [Stocks].[dbo].[product]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = DataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            DataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["ProductCode"].ToString();
            DataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Productname"].ToString();
            DataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["qty"].ToString();                
            if ((bool)item["productstatus"])
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = "Active";
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = "Deactive";
            }
```

Comment: This question has already an accepted answer, what your answer will add to the accepted answer? what is the difference? you should explain in your answer instead of only put your codes as an answer.