# Why am I getting "Specified cast is not valid."?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

It's pointing to the line `Id = dataReader.GetGuid(0),` of

```
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        Partners.Add(new Partner {
            Id = dataReader.GetGuid(0),
            Name = dataReader.GetString(1),
            Email = dataReader.GetString(2),
            Finished = dataReader.GetInt32(3) == 1
        });
    }
}
```

I've verified that **both `Id` and `dataReader.GetGuid(0)` are of type `Guid`**, if you can believe that.

`Id` is of type `Guid` because it's a field from

```
public class Partner
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
}
```

and `dataReader.GetGuid(0)` is of type `Guid` because when I do

```
public class Partner
{
    //public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
Id = dataReader.GetString(0)
```

I get the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'

Makes no sense!

**EDIT:** It does look I am getting values our when I implicitly type:

[image]

Comment: Do you have *null*s in the cursor? What `dataReader.GetValue(0).GetType()` returns?

Comment: Possible by-way: `Id = new Guid(Convert.ToString(dataReader.GetValue(0)))`

Comment: The data in column 0 of your `dataReader` likely can't be converted to a `Guid`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699781/specified-cast-is-not-valid

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Just checked an it returns `null`. Hmmm. Any idea why? The sproc I'm calling gets all columns from a T-SQL table generated by `CREATE TABLE Partners ( 
 id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
 name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 email NVARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
 finished BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

Comment: @user5648283: that's the table, and what's the *query* and the *stored procedure* then?

Comment: @user5648283 the sproc is simply `CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllPartners
AS
 SELECT * FROM Partners;`

Answer (score 0):

`dataReader.GetString(0)` returns a `String` and it will not implicitly cast your `Guid` to `String`, thus your `InvalidCastException`.

Try:

```
Id = dataReader.GetGuid(0).ToString()
```

Also, try to get values by using `String` indexer, not `integer` indexer:

```
Id = dataReader.GetGuid("Id"),
Name = dataReader.GetString("Name"),
Email = dataReader.GetString("Email"),
Finished = dataReader.GetInt32("Finished") == 1
```

Otherwise, adding columns to the result will break your code.

Even better, try to use `EntityFramework` to do all the mappings for you.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the most old-fashioned way possible

Comment: I don't see a `GetGuid(string)` method here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader(v=vs.110).aspx ....

Comment: I have found it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getguid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Alexei, the input parameter type is Int32, so you CANNOT DO dataReader.GetGuid("Id") . It is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer. If you want to use Guid type for the Id in Partner class, when you read your data from SQL Server, convert the string data type returned from the server to Guid type as below

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    Partners.Add(new Partner {
    Id = Guid.Parse(dataReader.GetString(0)),
    Name = dataReader.GetString(1),
    Email = dataReader.GetString(2),
    Finished = dataReader.GetInt32(3) == 1 });
}
```

But your partner class will have Id type Guid as below

```
public class Partner
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I ended up having to do this with a nullable guid;  uRow.UserRoleId = oRow["UserRoleId"] as Guid?;

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when trying to cast action arguments to `Guid`.

```
Guid.Parse(context.ActionArguments["someArgument"])
```

Issue here was [ActionArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.actionarguments?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is an IDictionary which contains objects like `IDictionary<string, object>`

When trying to cast `object` to `Guid`, the error comes. Solution was to convert it to a string and then do the casting.

```
Guid.Parse(context.ActionArguments["someArgument"].ToString());
```